# mongodb using results from a query as search criteria

Tags: mongodb

**Data set:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bf0e644d83f427bb4917"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "001", "site" : "A", "faultCode" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bfb1644d83f427bb4918"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "001", "site" : "B", "faultCode" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4919"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "001", "site" : "C", "faultCode" : "30" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4920"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "002", "site" : "A", "faultCode" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4921"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "002", "site" : "B", "faultCode" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4922"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 10", "PSCode" : "002", "site" : "C", "faultCode" : "30" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4923"), "hours" : "2019-08-01 00", "PSCode" : "001", "site" : "A", "faultCode" : "30" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4924"), "hours" : "2019-08-01 00", "PSCode" : "002", "site" : "A", "faultCode" : "30" }
```

The rule is that if there is a data with a `faultCode` of 30, the `PSCode` is not normal, and I only need to pay attention to the latest data, so I will first query the time of the latest data.

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([
    {
        "$group":{
            _id: "$PSCode",
            hours: {"$max": "$hours"}
        }
    }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "001", "hours" : "2019-08-29 10"}
{ "_id" : "002", "hours" : "2019-08-29 10"}
```

Then I want to check if `PSCode` is normal using `_id` and `hours`

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            PSCode: "001",
            hours: "2019-08-29 10"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group":{
            _id: "$PSCode",
            faultCode: {"$max": "$faultCode"}
        }
    }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "001", "faultCode" : 30}
```

**So how can I implement it with a query? Thanks very much in advance.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort:{
            "hours":-1,
            "faultCode":-1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$PSCode",
            "PSCode":{
                $first:"$PSCode"
            },
            "faultCode":{
                $first:"$faultCode"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{  
            "_id":0,
            "PSCode":1,
            "faultCode":1,
            "isNormal":{
                $ne:[
                    "$faultCode",
                    "30"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data Set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bf0e644d83f427bb4917"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "001",
    "site" : "A",
    "faultCode" : "0"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bfb1644d83f427bb4918"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "001",
    "site" : "B",
    "faultCode" : "0"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4919"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "001",
    "site" : "C",
    "faultCode" : "30"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4920"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "002",
    "site" : "A",
    "faultCode" : "0"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4921"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "002",
    "site" : "B",
    "faultCode" : "0"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4922"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "PSCode" : "002",
    "site" : "C",
    "faultCode" : "30"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4923"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-01 00",
    "PSCode" : "001",
    "site" : "A",
    "faultCode" : "30"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4924"),
    "hours" : "2019-08-01 00",
    "PSCode" : "002",
    "site" : "A",
    "faultCode" : "30"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "PSCode" : "002", "faultCode" : "30", "isNormal" : false }
{ "PSCode" : "001", "faultCode" : "30", "isNormal" : false }
```

**Explanation:** We are sorting the documents on the basis of `hour` and `faultCode` in descending order. Thus on the top would be the document with the latest hour and max fault code. We can then just pick the first document from the list for each `PSCode`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this method solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below query matches all the documents having "faultCode":30, which indicates the PSCode is not normal.

After that, it groups the documents based on "hours" field as we only want the latest documents.

After getting the documents grouped by "hours", the result is sorted based on the "hours" field and the documents are limited by an adding a limit of 1, which provides us the latest documents.

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate({
    $match:{
        "faultCode": "30"
    },
},
{
    $group:{
        "_id": "$hours",
        records: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "_id": -1
    }
},
{
    $limit: 1
})
```

**Output:**

It contains the latest documents with faultCode:30 and both have the latest value for "hours" field.

```
{
    "_id" : "2019-08-29 10",
    "records" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d68af0cd74c7263d9f853ab"),
            "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
            "PSCode" : "001",
            "site" : "C",
            "faultCode" : "30"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d68af0cd74c7263d9f853ae"),
            "hours" : "2019-08-29 10",
            "PSCode" : "002",
            "site" : "C",
            "faultCode" : "30"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this query will go wrong when ```PSCode``` has different latest time.